# Which directories should I include in my backup to use pass on another computer?

Tags: backup

I'm using the terminal program `pass` to store passwords. I want to make sure that I can access these passwords on another computer if this one ever gets compromised.

What directories should I back up?

Answer (score 2):

It stores everything in your home directory, specifically in `~/.password-store`

Note that you can look up documentation for most Ubuntu commands by finding their manpage - for example, for the `pass` command you can either use the command `man pass` from a console window, or do a Google search for `ubuntu manpage pass`

In this case the latter found me this: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pass.1.html

Comment: ok; thanks; what about gpg keys? are they needed? if so, can I just carry them to another computer or are they bound to this pc in some way?

Comment: From what I can tell from the documentation, all keys you need are generated uniquely to the user account and stored also within that directory.  You run an init command first to set up a gpg key identification.  The fact they support placing it into a git repository strongly implies everything in there can be shared and synced elsewhere.